# EntityFramework.pdb cannot be found

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, azure, debug-symbols

I have a WCF service running on azure and it gives this exception sometimes at random:

> The underlying provider failed on Open.

There was no inner exception so I started looking into this. I enabled azure diagnostics so I could trace and log this exception.

I found out that this Exception is thrown whenever the following exception is thrown:

> (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException)   Exception Message = "Unable to
>   connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."

So I looked in to this and found out that EntityFramework.pdb cannot be found.

[image: logs]

I tried solving this by checking `Microsoft Symbol Servers`. This does not solve the problem.
[image: pdb not found]

Some extra information :
The mysql database is made with a code first approach.

Mysql logged this :
[image: logs mysql]

Comment: Why do you want the PDB file? The exception seems clear enough to me: your MySQL server is blocking new connections.

Comment: the .PDB file won't help you to troubleshoot this error, as it's not a problem with Entity Framework; it's a problem with the number of connections your MySQL instance can handle.  As a side note, where is the MySQL instance hosted? have you looked at the logs there?

Comment: @AndrewCounts It is hosted on a linux server. My co-student has access to it. I will ask for the logs asap. Thanks for steering me in the right direction.

Comment: right so have you looked at that server to verify that it's up and there are no errors on it when you encounter the errors in your app?

Comment: @AndrewCounts I checked the logs. And apparently the wcf never closes the db connections. I fixed this by adding using() to my methods. I tried again and I still get the exception sometimes.